# Want to learn the new iMovie

Tags: imovie

Can you recommend a good site with some online training for the latest iMovie on OS X? I have tried to play with iMovie over the years and I never seem to 'get' how it is meant to be used.

Right now I have about 1.5 hours of raw video taken with my iPhone 5s of a set of student presentation and I (naively) wanted to make a short 'highlight real' of it. But once I import the video into iMovie I am not sure how to use its features.

(Note that I am very proficient on my mac in every other respect, software development, html, photoshop, illustrator, all those I manage just fine, but iMovie is so confusing. I feel like I just need a 20 minute leg up in a tutorial or something like that.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm generally a fan of Lynda.com. If you are a student (especially in a college environment), you may have free access to Lynda at your library. It looks like there are a series of tutorials for iMovie on their site:

http://www.lynda.com/iMovie-training-tutorials/229-0.html

Alternatively, if you search Youtube for iMovie training, you'll likely some good stuff as well (even reposted Lynda.com videos). I suspect that after about an hour of video tutorials you'd have a good sense of the key features of iMovie.